# Any way to sort large objects without cmp sort argument?

Tags: python

When I use an external API, it dumps me with an array where each element is a dictionary with many keys. With the deprecation of the cmp parameter in Python3, am I forced to write class that looks like this?

```
@total_ordering
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, field1, field2, field3, field4, ..., field100):
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
        self.field3 = field3
        self.field4 = field4
        ...
        self.field100 = field100

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # some complex way to do ordering
        a = self.field3 * self.field4 - self.field5
        b = other.field3 * other.field4 - other.field5
        return a < b
```

My problem here is being forced to turn this large dictionary into a class object where I would have to write such long constructor if I wanted all the values. This would have been done in Python2 as:

```
def compare(a, b):
    # some complex way to do ordering
    a = self.field3 * self.field4 - self.field5
    b = other.field3 * other.field4 - other.field5
    return a < b

sorted([dict1, dict2, ..., dict1000], cmp=compare)
```

Comment: You gave us your half-way solution. Can you describe the original problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your code.  There is no `self` or `other` defined in your `compare()` function, and if these are really dicts the `[dot]field_name` syntax doesn't make sense either.  Please give _real code_ if you want a real answer.  Or just use the `cmp_to_key` function I already showed in my edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's sort only uses `__lt__`, so there's no need to define `__eq__` or `__ne__` if all you want to do is sort objects.

But most people would use the optional `key=` argument:

```
array_of_those_things.sort(key=lambda x: x.field2)
```

It will run faster that way too - instead of looking up `field2` twice on every one of the `O(N*log(N))` comparisons, the `key=` argument will cause `sort()` to retrieve `field2` exactly one from each object in the list, and use the cached values throughout the sort.

You'll also see things like:

```
import operator
array_of_those_things.sort(key=operator.itemgetter("field2"))
```

BTW, the code I gave here probably won't actually work, because you didn't show how you access the fields of the original objects, just how you accessed fields *after* you stuffed the objects into some artificial class.  So you'll have to adjust the `key=` function to how your original objects actually behave.

### Lazy but not recommended

In any Python 2 case where you were doing

```
somelist.sort(cmp=f)
```

you *can* do this in Python 3 instead:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key
somelist.sort(key=cmp_to_key(f))
```

But that's needlessly inefficient in almost all cases.  Indeed, `cmp=` itself in Python 2 was usually needlessly inefficient.  If at all possible, use Python 3's `key=` as intended.  But until you give precise details about your original data, I can't guess what they are ;-)

Comment: When I complained about writing a lot of code was the part in the constructor. In order to now translate the dictionary into a class object I am writing 100 lines of code just to copy the fields. Before I used to just leave the dictionary alone and write comparer function to sort conveniently.

Comment: Do you understand the answer?  Best I can tell, there's no reason at all to create class objects.  But you didn't show your original data.  Instead of spelling out your actual problem, you're "complaining" about an attempt at a solution that's was _probably_ off base from the start.  Try reading the answer again after doing the best you can to forget that you ever considered stuffing the original data into a class.  If that doesn't help, back up and spell out the original problem instead (not the attempt at a solution that you already know you don't like).

Comment: For example, _show_ the exact code you would have used in Python 2.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit there.

Comment: See the edit for a non-recommended but wholly mechanical way to make tiny changes to Python 2 `cmp=` code that will work with Python 3's `key=` scheme.

Comment: I would like to use the key parameter since it would be more efficient when sorting. Besides the cmp_to_key function, writing up a class to provide the complex comparison logic is the only way to sort with the new approach?